# Unable to retrieve input values in table row using a dropdown - but able to retrieve dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I am close, but my (little) knowledge has come to an end...

When executing this function, my LLORDa and LLINEa are not retrieving the values from the table row (thus not inserting all values into my table). My SVCDESC from the drop down IS getting the selected value thankfully. Any ideas? Thanks in advance guys!

```
    <script>

        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("input:submit, input[type=button], input[type=submit], button, .button").button();
        });

function saveSMR()
        {
            var SVCDescDropDown = $(this); 
            var row = SVCDescDropDown.closest("tr.row"); 

            var LORDaInput = row.find("input[name=LORDa]");
            var LLINEaInput = row.find("input[name=LLINEa]");  

            jQuery.ajax(
            {
                url: 'B2BORD493.PGM', 
                type: 'POST',
                data: {task: 'savServMiss', LORDa: LORDaInput.val(), LLINEa: LLINEaInput.val(), SVCDESC: SVCDescDropDown.val()},                
            }).done(function(message)
            {

                alert(row.length);
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');      
            }); 

            console.log(LORDaInput.val() + LLINEaInput.val());      
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                $("select[name=SVCDESC]").on("change", saveSMR);
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false
});
$("#pbutton").on("click", function() {
$("#dialog").dialog("open");

});
});
 });
    </script>



<tr class="row"> 
<td class="text num">1043121</td>
 <td class="text num">22</td>
  <select name="SVCDESC">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value='STK'>No Stock</option>
    <option value='TES'Test Desc</option>
    </select>

  </td>
  <input type="hidden" name="LLINEa" />
  <input type="hidden" name="LORDa" />
</tr>
```

Comment: My god, my formatting of this question is appalling! Trying to edit now!

Comment: What does `row.find("input[name=LORDa]");` for example return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: Sorry I misread your question. There are no values assigned to the hidden field that you are calling. Maybe that is why there are no values?

```
<input type="hidden" name="LLINEa" />
<input type="hidden" name="LORDa" />
```

Perhaps something like these will return some values?

```
<input type="hidden" name="LLINEa" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="LORDa" value="abc" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean add value to:       
<input type="hidden" name="LLINEa" value="<field name=LORD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="LORDa" value="<field name=LLINE"/>

Comment: Not exactly. You are creating two hidden input fields which do not have their own value. Hence, theoretically you should not be able to get any value.

To give the hidden input field a value you need to do something like this.
<input type="hidden" name="LLINEa" value="This field value" />.

So that when you are calling to get the value of the field it will return "This field value".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have managed to get it working now. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I can be of help.